# What is the difference between setting the yscale in log and setting the y variable in log?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I would like to know what is the difference between:

```
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.plot(a,b)
```

and

```
ax.plot(a,np.log10(b))
```

Here in the first case we are just setting the **yscale** to be a log scale.

In the second case we log the `b`, i.e the y axes variable in `log10` and then plot.

They both seem to give different results. As an example I have taken:

```
a = np.linspace(0,2,100)
b = np.cos(a)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_yscale('log')

ax.plot(a,b,'-o')
plt.show()
```

This gives [image]

Then when we use:

```
ax.plot(a,np.log10(b),'-o')
```

we get [image]

Answer (score 2):

You gave it different data in the first and the second graph. Once transformed, the other not. Whatever the axis' scale, coordinates "(1,100)" will always be "(1,100)", whether it is labeled "(1,100)" or "(1,10^2)". One uses a log scale not to transform the data, but to have a more readable graph when some points are far away.

By applying the log yourself you transform your data. Then in your second graph you have to interpret yourself that "2" actually means "10^2".

Apart from that, the only visual difference is only the y axis' ticks, which you could also change to log scale "by hand" if you were very patient. 
I advise to change the scale on the axis rather than on the data, because first it probably handles automatically negative/zero cases, and secondly when you want to add stuff such as arrows etc. to point a position in your graph, good luck scaling it yourself.

Comment: But the first one has only positive values and the second one has the proper `log10` values for each variable.. why is this difference present?

Comment: So when we say it is a `log-log` plot, do we mean the first plot or the second plot?

Comment: there is no difference between plotting f(x) against x in log-log to plotting log10(f(x)) vs log10(x) in the 'real world'. it's the same.
For matplotlib the only difference is, that you tell matplotlib you want the nice labels and gridlines and ticks for a log-log plot.
It's the same difference like choosing the log-log paper for drawing the graph instead of normal square paper.

Comment: @MaxNoe I would argue that there is a huge difference, in one case the units are your data units, in the other, they are log(data_units).  In either case you must keep track of what you are doing and properly label your axises.

Comment: @ThePredator When we say a `log-log` plot it means that both axes x and y are in log scale. So, none of your examples but more like the first when you also `ax.set_xscale('log')`; or the second with `ax.plot(np.log10(a),np.log10(b),'-o')`, but then again, up to you to interpret the numbers on your axes as powers of 10.

Comment: @MaxNoe: as tcaswell has pointed out, there is a difference that you clearly see in the graph

Comment: @muraveill: So you are saying that if I set both the scales, i.e `ax.set_xscale('log')` and `ax.set_yscale('log')` it is a `log-log` plot?

Comment: where do you see a difference in the graph? I'm not talkin about limits or labels.

Comment: @ThePredator Yes, this is what I am saying.

Comment: @MaxNoe: when you scale the axis, i.e `ax.set_yscale('log')` you can see the values are all positive starting from 1 to 10^-2. But when you set your y variable to `np.log10(b)`, then you can see they take into acount the `log10` values for `b`, which gives us negative values in the yaxis. So they are not one and the same!!

Comment: To summary, `ax.set_yscale('log')` in the background transforms your data to log just like you would do it yourself, except it adapts the ticks accordingly, which you need to do yourself if you transform the data yourself (or just change the axis' legend). A "negative value" is not one if you know that "-2" on the axis actually means "10^-2".

Comment: @muraveill: Are you sure that the negative values in the second graph are not negative? Because for example `np.log10(cos(1.47)) = -1.0` and you are saying it should be assumed `10^-1`!! If that is what is the answer, then I am baffled

Comment: I am quite certain that cos(1.47) is positive, and that the log of cos(1.47) is negative. If you want to consider the log of your data, it is negative. If you just want the cos value on a log scale, then cos(1.47) is positive no matter what the scale is. The scale only means "how do I want to space the points on my graph?" and the log scale is the answer "close to each other even if they are not close originally".

Comment: If you did not really want to transform your data and get negative numbers, then you can still obtain a log scale by transforming to log, but then you must adapt the ticks (-2 -> 10^-2 etc.) on the axis to show what the data originally is. And this is what matplotlib did for your first graph.